# adobe AIR - suggesting that the user update to the latest version

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, ane

I am a as3 programmer,
How to make the old user prompted to update the latest app version? 
use ANE?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html)
You can find documentation for the [ApplicationUpdaterUI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdaterUI.html)
Read the documentation with attention to learn how to setup the server side files.
EDIT:not sure what you mean by use ANE, so edit your question to make it clear, the above works with .air files installers , can you be more specific, what platform are you targeting? did you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apple or Android push notifications. But for a simple in-app prompt just have the app check, when it's launched, for a text or html file with a particular file name that you've put on a server. The file's text is your prompt. The app can display it however you like. The prompt can contain a URL that can take you right to the download link for the update.

Read up on the File and Filestream classes. It's pretty easy to do this.